# Data not showing in table form when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I ran the below code in Jupyter Notebook, I was expecting the output to appear like an excel table but instead the output was split up and not in a table. How can I get it to show up in table format?

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Robbery_2014_to_2019.csv")

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
           X          Y  Index_ event_unique_id            occurrencedate  \
0 -79.270393  43.807190   17430   GO-2015134200  2015-01-23T14:52:00.000Z   
1 -79.488281  43.764091   19205  GO-20142956833  2014-09-21T23:30:00.000Z   
2 -79.215836  43.761856   15831   GO-2015928336  2015-03-23T11:30:00.000Z   
3 -79.436264  43.642963   16727  GO-20142711563  2014-08-15T22:00:00.000Z   
4 -79.369461  43.654526   20091  GO-20142492469  2014-07-12T19:00:00.000Z   

               reporteddate premisetype  ucr_code  ucr_ext  \
0  2015-01-23T14:57:00.000Z     Outside      1610      210   
1  2014-09-21T23:37:00.000Z     Outside      1610      200   
2  2015-06-03T15:08:00.000Z       Other      1610      220   
3  2014-08-16T00:09:00.000Z   Apartment      1610      200   
4  2014-07-14T01:35:00.000Z   Apartment      1610      100   

               offence  ...  occurrencedayofyear occurrencedayofweek  \
0   Robbery - Business  ...                 23.0          Friday       
1    Robbery - Mugging  ...                264.0          Sunday       
2      Robbery - Other  ...                 82.0          Monday       
3    Robbery - Mugging  ...                227.0          Friday       
4  Robbery With Weapon  ...                193.0          Saturday     

   occurrencehour      MCI Division  Hood_ID                 Neighbourhood  \
0              14  Robbery      D42      129         Agincourt North (129)   
1              23  Robbery      D31       27  York University Heights (27)   
2              11  Robbery      D43      137                  Woburn (137)   
3              22  Robbery      D11       86             Roncesvalles (86)   
4              19  Robbery      D51       73                Moss Park (73)   

        Long        Lat  ObjectId  
0 -79.270393  43.807190      2001  
1 -79.488281  43.764091      2002  
2 -79.215836  43.761856      2003  
3 -79.436264  43.642963      2004  
4 -79.369461  43.654526      2005  

[5 rows x 29 columns]
```

Comment: Don't use `print()` just type `df.head()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `display(df.head())` (produces slightly nicer output than without `display()`

Answer (score 0):

Print function is applied to represent any kind of information like string or estimated value.
Whereas Display() will display the dataset in